# Using a comma after a question mark inside quotation marks?

Tags: style-manuals

Can I use a comma following a question mark (as part of a title), inside quotation marks?

It sounds like quite a complicated question, but all I want to do is correctly write the sentence:

> "Leo Strauss, in his essay “What is Political Philosophy?,” takes a
>   radically anti-historical view, contradicting Nietzsche and relegating
>   Nietzsche's critique to the edges of meaningful discourse."

Comment: I sometimes doubly punctuate around terminal quotes, but never within. The question-mark will do double duty here: you don't need the comma.

Answer (score 0):

This really is a purely stylistic question. It’s worth hanging around [writers.se] as these sorts of questions come up there occasionally.

Personally (and this is just an opinion, so kinda asking for this to be put on hold), I would italicise the title, and probably leave out both the commas and the quotation marks, but if I were writing within any kind of “house style” this is subject to change.

Ultimately the most important criteria are to (a) be understandable to your readers; and (b) where possible remain legible both to readers raised in the previous generation to yourself, and to those in the next generation.